# Select elements from multi-dimensional array, using string (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, explode

I have a multi dimensional array in PHP

```
$somearray = array(
    'item1' => array(
        'subitem1' => 'Some value',
        'subitem2' => 'Some other value',
        'subitem3'  => array(
            'subsubitem' => 'A sub value'
        )
    ),
    'item2' => 'a different value'
);
```

I then have a string *map* which represents which value I want to select:

```
"item1/subitem3/subsubitem"
```

How can I convert from that string *map* of an array, into:

```
$wanted_value = $somearray['item1']['subitem3']['subsubitem'];
```

but keeping in mind the array could be any number of levels deep.

Comment: `explode` your path, then traverse the array with a recursive function.

Comment: I don't think it should be recursive

Comment: Just for fun: `eval('$wanted_value = $somearray["' . str_replace("/",'"]["',$map) . '"];');` Done! But seriously, use @TobSpr's method. =)

Comment: well, that's at least creative :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way (should also check to make sure the keys exists):

```
$path   = explode("/", "item1/subitem3/subsubitem");
$result = $somearray;

foreach($path as $k) {
    $result = $result[$k];
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: I actually used this over @TobSpr as I found it easier to add some basic sanity checking with a `if (isset($result[$k]))` in the process, but both solutions worked perfectly. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
$parts = explode("/", $map);

$currentData = $somearray;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++) {
    $currentData = $currentData[$parts[$i]];
}

$result = $currentData;
```